# How to add relations to make groups trivial

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

Suppose I have a group $G = <x, y|x^2y^5>$, and I want to add a single relation to make G trivial. Is there any way to do this? In general, if we have a group $G = <x, y|r>$, where r is a single relation, is there a good way to find another relation that when added makes the group trivial? Is there an area of study that deals with these "equations"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this in general. It would not be possible for example if you took $r = a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$.

But in this example you could for example add $xy^2$. In the group $H = \langle x,y \mid x^2y^5, xy^2 \rangle$, we have $x = y^{-2}$ from the second relator, and hence the first relator becomes just $y$, so $H$ is trivial.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll go through some simple examples and see if there are any patterns to get a feel of when there will be a solution. Because I imagine from your solution it may always be possible to do with $r = x^ny^m$

Comment: Maybe not $x^2y^2$ actually. And I'm skeptical about $x^5y^7$. I think it maybe works if there exists $k$ such that $|k*m - n| = 1$, or $|k*n - m| = 1$

Comment: With $r=x^5y^7$ you could add $x^2y^3$. The necessary and sufficient condition is for $n$ and $m$ to be coprime.